# Using searchapi module on a drupal multisite installation

Tags: search

We are setting up a Drupal multisite installation, which is going to look like

```
themastersite.edu
themastersite.edu/somethinglikethesubsite1
themastersite.edu/somethinglikethesubsite2 and so long
```

I've read some documentaition around Searchapi module, but I can't find out if there is a possibility to have, in themastersite.edu, a searchapi page that should search in all subsites ?

Any help or link, welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You declared that searchapi is the solution but actually [Solr Multisite](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_multisitesearch) can do this.

Comment: Hi :) 
Sure, Solr Multisite should made it but as we"re already using Searchapi on others websites, the idea was to keep that one (searchapi).